# How can I pass using a for-loop in an Angular object to a string that gets rendered by $sce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, for-loop

I am currently rendering a chunk of html and directives using $sce.trustAsHtml.

I used a directive called compile-template which allows me to use ng-directives such as ng-click, and ng-disabled.

I am able to pass in objects if they are static (such as name: 'winning'), BUT if I am cycling through them using a forEach loop, i get an `undefined` result.

Example:

```
$scope.xxx = {
name: "winning",
array:["test","123","456","888"]
};

var string = 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#" ng-mouseover="removeExp()">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em> <button ng-click="fire(a)">TEST</button>'
   angular.forEach($scope.xxx.array, function (a) {

string += 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#" ng-mouseover="removeExp()">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em> <button ng-click="fire(a)">TEST</button> <button ng-click="works(xxx.name)">Works</button>'
  });



 $scope.myHTML =$sce.trustAsHtml(string);
```

I have a working jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3J25M/533/

(^open up dev tools to see console.log^)

Notice how the 'Works' button does work, but the **'TEST' button does not**.  (the 'TEST' button gets its object property from a forEach loop.)

---

How can i pass in a value using angular.forEach?

Thanks!

Comment: the problem isn't about looping or anything, the loop variable (a) simply doesn't exist outside the foreach callback

Comment: if that is the case, how can i get a different array value to appear in each button?  When i click the first 'TEST' button, array[0] appears, when I click the second 'TEST' button, array[1] appears... etc

Comment: my question is how can i assign each of the array values (array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3]) to each of the 4 'TEST' buttons.  This can be accomplished using a ng-repeat.  But i cant use a ng-repeat in this scenario (using $sce) to my knowledge.  How can I assign the values if the for-loop is out of scope?

Comment: i've posted an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to access the array, and use the index value from the foreach. This allows access to the scope variable. Notice the value of i and not the string, this is important.

```
angular.forEach($scope.xxx.array, function (a, i) {

  string += 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#" ng-mouseover="removeExp()">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em> <button ng-click="fire(xxx.array[' + i + '])">TEST</button> <button ng-click="works(xxx.name)">Works</button>'
});
```

For instance, it will generate the following:

```
ng-click="fire(xxx.array[0])"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Please check working example: Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3J25M/543/)

Replce your angular.forEach with following code

```
angular.forEach($scope.xxx.array, function(a) {
  string += 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#" ng-mouseover="removeExp()">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em> <button ng-click="fire(' + a + ')">TEST</button> <button ng-click="works(xxx.name)">Works</button>'
});
```

What is wrong in your

```
<button ng-click="fire(a)">TEST</button>
```

Here you have to replace "fire(a)" with

```
fire( ' + a + ') as you are referring variable
```

Comment: this is a bit different as you're outputting the value as it is at that time rather than a reference to the variable. not sure if it matters or not, but if the value changed the click would produce a stale result

Comment: Sorry, I did'nt understand what are you trying to say.